# Showing that the matrix transformation $T(f) = x*f'(x)+f''(x)$ is linear

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to show that the following matrix transformation is linear.

$T(f) = x*f'(x)+f''(x)$

I know I have to show that $T(f+g) = T(f) + T(g)$ but I don't understand what $T(f+g)$ will look like.

Is $T(f+g) = x*(f'(x)+g'(x))+(f''(x)+(g''(x))$ the correct interpretation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the definition of $T$, you have for every function $h$ in your domain of $T$, that 
$$ T(h) = x\cdot h'(x) + h''(x) $$
If now $h = f+g$, we get 
$$ T(f+g) = x \cdot (f+g)'(x) + (f+g)''(x), $$
which equals your calculated result, which moreover used the linearity of differentiation.

Comment: Yeah, this is what I was looking for, thanks. About time to get the basics down.